Subject-level filtering within a date range across two dataframes using dplyr
I'm looking to filter the data in one dataframe (Target) based of whether or not a value in another dataframe (Reference) falls between two dates in the Target dataframe.
For example, this would be my raw data (Target):



ParticipantId
Date1
Date2




10001
1/02/2010
1/02/2015


10001
3/02/2016
1/02/2018


10001
1/02/2019
1/02/2020


10001
1/02/2021
1/02/2023


10002
1/02/2016
1/02/2018


10002
1/02/2019
1/02/2020


10002
1/02/2021
1/02/2023


10003
1/02/2013
1/02/2020


10003
1/02/2021
1/02/2023



And this would be my reference data (Reference):



ParticipantId
DateA




10001
3/12/2013


10002
5/15/2022


10003
9/20/2022



What I would like is a filtered output of of Target where DateA in Reference falls between Date1 and Date2 in Target like so:



ParticipantId
Date1
Date2




10001
1/02/2010
1/02/2015


10002
1/02/2021
1/02/2023


10003
1/02/2021
1/02/2023



If anyone would be able to provide some input as to how this could be done, preferably without using a join as the real Target is too big to load into memory using dplyr with pipes, I would greatly appreciate it.
Code to make the dataframes may be found below but you may need to load the lubridate library.
Reference <- structure(
  list(
    ParticipantId = 10001:10003,
    DateA = c("3/12/2013", "5/15/2022", "9/20/2022")
  ),
  class = "data.frame",
  row.names = c(NA, -3L)
)

Target <- structure(
  list(
    ParticipantId = c(
      10001L,
      10001L,
      10001L,
      10001L,
      10002L,
      10002L,
      10002L,
      10003L,
      10003L
    ),
    Date1 = c(
      "1/2/2010",
      "1/2/2016",
      "1/2/2019",
      "1/2/2021",
      "1/2/2016",
      "1/2/2019",
      "1/2/2021",
      "1/2/2019",
      "1/2/2021"
    ),
    Date2 = c(
      "1/2/2015",
      "1/2/2018",
      "1/2/2020",
      "1/2/2023",
      "1/2/2018",
      "1/2/2020",
      "1/2/2023",
      "1/2/2020",
      "1/2/2023"
    )
  ),
  class = "data.frame",


"Target" is too big to load into memory? Then you may need arrow or another tool that can work with data that is larger than memory.

First you need to convert the Date columns from strings to dates. Since they are in the m-d-YYYY format, you can use
lubridate::mdy to do that.
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
Reference <- structure(
  list(
    ParticipantId = 10001:10003,
    DateA = c("3/12/2013", "5/15/2022", "9/20/2022")
  ),
  class = "data.frame",
  row.names = c(NA, -3L)
)

Target <- data.frame(
    ParticipantId = c(10001L, 10001L,10001L,10001L,10002L,10002L,10002L,10003L,10003L),
    Date1 = c("1/2/2010","1/2/2016","1/2/2019","1/2/2021","1/2/2016","1/2/2019","1/2/2021","1/2/2019","1/2/2021"),
    Date2 = c("1/2/2015","1/2/2018","1/2/2020","1/2/2023","1/2/2018","1/2/2020","1/2/2023","1/2/2020","1/2/2023"))

Target$Date1 <- mdy(Target$Date1)
Target$Date2 <- mdy(Target$Date2)
Reference$DateA <- mdy(Reference$DateA)

Next, join the data so that you have DataA corresponding to each Partipicant_ID in your Target data.
joined_data <- left_join(Target, Reference, by = join_by(ParticipantId)) 
print(joined_data)
  ParticipantId      Date1      Date2      DateA
1         10001 2010-01-02 2015-01-02 2013-03-12
2         10001 2016-01-02 2018-01-02 2013-03-12
3         10001 2019-01-02 2020-01-02 2013-03-12
4         10001 2021-01-02 2023-01-02 2013-03-12
5         10002 2016-01-02 2018-01-02 2022-05-15
6         10002 2019-01-02 2020-01-02 2022-05-15
7         10002 2021-01-02 2023-01-02 2022-05-15
8         10003 2019-01-02 2020-01-02 2022-09-20
9         10003 2021-01-02 2023-01-02 2022-09-20

Lastly, use dplyr::filter and dplyr::between to keep only records where DateA is between Date1 and Date2
joined_data_between_dates_1_and_2 <- filter(joined_data, between(DateA, Date1, Date2)) 
print(joined_data_between_dates_1_and_2)
 ParticipantId      Date1      Date2      DateA
1         10001 2010-01-02 2015-01-02 2013-03-12
2         10002 2021-01-02 2023-01-02 2022-05-15
3         10003 2021-01-02 2023-01-02 2022-09-20

Oh and if you don't want DateA in your final output you could add one more step:
joined_data_between_dates_1_and_2 <- select(joined_data_between_dates_1_and_2, -DateA)

If you're a bit more familiar with dplyr and 'the pipe', you could do it in one simple sequence like this:
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
Reference <- structure(
  list(
    ParticipantId = 10001:10003,
    DateA = c("3/12/2013", "5/15/2022", "9/20/2022")
  ),
  class = "data.frame",
  row.names = c(NA, -3L)
)

Target <- data.frame(
    ParticipantId = c(10001L, 10001L,10001L,10001L,10002L,10002L,10002L,10003L,10003L),
    Date1 = c("1/2/2010","1/2/2016","1/2/2019","1/2/2021","1/2/2016","1/2/2019","1/2/2021","1/2/2019","1/2/2021"),
    Date2 = c("1/2/2015","1/2/2018","1/2/2020","1/2/2023","1/2/2018","1/2/2020","1/2/2023","1/2/2020","1/2/2023"))

Reference <- Reference |> mutate(DateA = mdy(DateA))

joined_data_between_dates_1_and_2 <- Target |> 
                                     mutate(Date1 = mdy(Date1), Date2 = mdy(Date2)) |> 
                                     left_join(Reference, by = join_by(ParticipantId)) |> 
                                     filter(between(DateA, Date1, Date2)) |> 
                                     select(-DateA)

If Target and Reference are very big, you can use the R arrow package and the paruqet format to speed things up and only load the full results into memory once it's finished.
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(arrow)
set.seed(123) 
# Function to generate 'n' random dates between a start and end date
generate_random_dates <- function(n, start_date, end_date) {
  start <- as.Date(start_date)
  end <- as.Date(end_date)
  random_dates <- start + runif(n, 0, as.numeric(difftime(end, start, units = "days")))
  return(random_dates)
}



#Generate Reference data.frame with 10 million ParticipantIds
Reference <- data.frame(
  ParticipantId = 1:(10^7),
  DateA = generate_random_dates(10^7, "2000-01-01", "2024-12-31")
)

#Generate Target data.frame with 100 million rows
Target <- data.frame(
  ParticipantId = sample(1:(10^7), 10^8, replace = TRUE),
  Date1 = generate_random_dates(10^8, "2000-01-01", "2024-12-31"),
  Date2 = generate_random_dates(10^8, "2000-01-01", "2024-12-31")
)

#Takes about 12-13 seconds on my computer. 
(Removed step to concert string dates to Dates 
# because the data.frames I made already are in that format).
system.time(Target |> 
  left_join(Reference, by = join_by(ParticipantId)) |> 
  filter(between(DateA, Date1, Date2)) |> 
  select(-DateA))



user  system elapsed 
12.19    0.63   12.82


#Save Reference and Target as arrow parquet files.
write_dataset(Reference, path = "reference", format = "parquet")
write_dataset(Target, path = "target", format = "parquet")

#Load arrow parquet files
target_arrow <- open_dataset("target")
reference_arrow <- open_dataset("reference")


system.time(target_arrow |> 
              left_join(reference_arrow, by = join_by(ParticipantId)) |> 
              filter(between(DateA, Date1, Date2)) |> 
              select(-DateA) |> 
              collect())

#About twice as fast
user  system elapsed 
7.58    0.37    6.29 


Thanks! Could it be done without the join?
Target is too big to be loaded into memory in the real data.

Perhaps just left_join(Reference, Target, join_by(ParticipantId, DateA >= Date1, DateA <= Date2)) since dplyr 1.1.0+ supports non-equi joins, so you can skip the filtering step.

Added a solution using the R arrow package to step things up and only fully load the final output into memory. About twice as fast.

The following code works. If the date-columns are already the correct str() for you, you can skip the mutate().
goal_df <- target |> 
  left_join(ref, by = "id") |> 
  mutate(
    dateA = as.Date(dateA, format = "%m/%d/%Y"),
    date1 = as.Date(date1, format = "%m/%d/%Y"),
    date2 = as.Date(date2, format = "%m/%d/%Y"),
  ) |> 
  filter(dateA <= date2 & dateA >= date1) |> 
  select(-dateA)

Hope this helps! :)

It does, but could it be done without the left join?
Target is too big to be loaded into memory in the real data.

I certainly might be mistaking. But I don't think there is a very simple way to do this task without loading target into memory if you want it all in one pipe.
Following are a couple of possible solutions:

Iterate over the ref-df and subset the target-df in chunks. Probably best with data.tables, which is more efficient in handling large dataframes. Can also be done with dplyr. But probably less efficient. Either way you won't be able to do it in one pipe.
Put you dataframe into a database and use 'dbplyr' to connect to it.


It should work if you have Target as an arrow table or a mapping to it and have a pipe for collect() at the very end.
Another factor I should have specified and apologies there.

The question says that Target exceeds memory but also refers to a Target data frame so we assume that what was meant was that that the data is too large to perform a join in memory but is small enough for the inputs and the result to fit. (If that is not the intention please clarify since it would be easy to modify this code to directly read .csv files into the data base avoiding R entirely except for the result.) We perform the join externally using duckdb.
First convert the Date* columns to Date class.
Then define a directory for duckdb, connect to it and register both data frames, perform the join outside of R and disconnect.
library(duckdb)
library (lubridate)

# fix dates
Reference$DateA <- mdy(Reference$DateA)
Target$Date1 <- mdy(Target$Date1)
Target$Date2 <- mdy(Target$Date2)

# create db    
db <- normalizePath("mydir.db", mustWork = FALSE)
con <- dbConnect(duckdb(), dbdir = db)
duckdb_register(con, "Reference", Reference)
duckdb_register(con, "Target", Target)

# join
res <- dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT r.* 
   FROM Reference AS r
   LEFT JOIN Target AS t 
     ON r.ParticipantId = t.ParticipantId AND
        r.DateA BETWEEN t.Date1 AND t.Date2")

res
##   ParticipantId      DateA
## 1         10001 2013-03-12
## 2         10002 2022-05-15
## 3         10003 2022-09-20

dbDisconnect(con, shutdown = TRUE)

Note
Reference <- data.frame(
  ParticipantId = 10001:10003,
  DateA = as.Date(c("2013-03-12", "2022-05-15", "2022-09-20"))
)

Target <- data.frame(
  ParticipantId = rep(10001:10003, 4:2),
  Date1 = as.Date(c(
    "2010-01-02", "2016-03-02", "2019-01-02", "2021-01-02", "2016-01-02",
    "2019-01-02", "2021-01-02", "2013-01-02", "2021-01-02"
  )),
  Date2 = as.Date(c(
    "2015-01-02", "2018-01-02", "2020-01-02", "2023-01-02", "2018-01-02",
    "2020-01-02", "2023-01-02", "2020-01-02", "2023-01-02"
  ))
)


I'm not sure I understand exactly what you mean by "Target is too big to load into memory." Maybe you mean that a cartesian join of all the Target data to all the Reference data, keyed to ParticipantID alone, is too big? In that case, a non-equi join where you use dplyr 1.1.0+ and join_by will help avoid the step of filtering from a much larger joined table.
If the issue is really that you can't load Target into memory, then you may need to use a package like arrow to work with larger-than-memory data. For instance:
https://r4ds.hadley.nz/arrow.html
https://arrow-user2022.netlify.app/
Strategy form joining two very large arrow datasets without blowing up memory usage

left_join(
  Reference |> mutate(across(DateA, lubridate::mdy)), 
  Target |> mutate(across(Date1:Date2, lubridate::mdy)), 
  join_by(ParticipantId, DateA >= Date1, DateA <= Date2))

output
 ParticipantId      DateA      Date1      Date2
1         10001 2013-03-12 2010-01-02 2015-01-02
2         10002 2022-05-15 2021-01-02 2023-01-02
3         10003 2022-09-20 2021-01-02 2023-01-02


This one is actually throwing:
Error in `handle_join_by()`: ! Inequality conditions and helper functions are not supported in `join_by()` expressions.
For me.

What version of dplyr are you using? That sounds like you are using a version older than 2023's v1.1.0. (Latest is 1.1.4 as of May 2024, but non-equi joins were added with 1.1.0)

packageVersion("dplyr") [1] ‘1.1.4’
So it should theoretically be working.

That sounds like it might be an error coming from arrow, which partly supports dplyr::join_by, but "limited only to equality conditions." https://github.com/apache/arrow/pull/33664 So I'd suggest trying it without arrow loaded, or separate the filtering into a separate step so arrow can handle it.
